# How to read a file after we open OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, file-io

I couldn't find any method to add in the if statement to read a text file. Here is the code;

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            OpenFileDialog BrowseFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            BrowseFile1.Title = "Select a text file";
            BrowseFile1.Filter = "Text File |*.txt";
            BrowseFile1.FilterIndex = 1;
            string ContainingFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            BrowseFile1.InitialDirectory = @ContainingFolder;
            //BrowseFile1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            BrowseFile1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (BrowseFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
```

I just wanna get whole text froma text file that I choose from this OpenFolderDialog window.

Comment: This is well documented at MSDN, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: You really couldn't find any method to fit there? Doubtfull.

Comment: I know how to read files but I don't know how to read a file which is defined by this OpenFileDialog method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(BrowseFile1.FileName);
```

Another possibility is using a StreamReader:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Just Change the file locatations through `BrowseFile1.FileName`.

Comment: Please note, I have changed BrowseFile1.Path to BrowseFile1.FileName, I had the wrong property in mind...